# Creating App using Parse.com REST API in Python

Tags: python, api, rest, parse-platform

Trying to create an app using Parse.com REST API in Python, I have used the code detailed in the [REST guide](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#apps) and adjusted a couple of things based on previous errors I received, however this one I'm really not sure where to go with:

```
import json,httplib
connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.parse.com', 443)
connection.connect()
connection.request('POST', '/1/apps', json.dumps("{'appName':'my new app','clientClassCreationEnabled':false}"), {
       "X-Parse-Email": "EMAIL",
       "X-Parse-Password": "PASSWORD",
       "Content-Type": "application/json"
       })
result = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())
print(result)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
{u'code': 256, u'error': u'App name is required to create a new app'}
```

Does anybody know a solution for this or where I might be going wrong? I haven't been able to find anything.

Cheers

Comment: Do you have account at parse.com?

Comment: Yes, just replaced the email/password fields with my login details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should pass dict to `json.dumps`, not a string

```
import json,httplib
connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.parse.com', 443)
connection.connect()
connection.request('POST', '/1/apps', json.dumps({'appName':'my new app','clientClassCreationEnabled':False}), {
   "X-Parse-Email": "EMAIL",
   "X-Parse-Password": "PASSWORD",
   "Content-Type": "application/json"
   })
result = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())
print(result)
```